# How to get the path where binaries of python modules are stores (usr/local/bin)

Tags: python, path, binaries

I am trying to run a python module "icdiff" using subprocess.Popen(). It is not recognizing icdiff as a command and asking for complete path.
icdiff is installed in /usr/local/bin, but it varies from platform to platform, for some platforms it was in /usr/bin.

How to get the path where this python module(icdiff) is installed. I tried

```
sys.executable
```

but it is always giving "/usr/bin/python". Are there any commands using which I can get the path where python binaries are stored.

Comment: It depends on how it was installed where it'll be located. Python doesn't keep track of where it is installed, no. In most cases you can assume it'll be in `sys.exec_prefix` though or `sys.base_exec_prefix` (the latter ignores virtual environments), plus `/bin` for POSIX systems, `/Scripts` for Windows, I'd say.

Comment: I may have that wrong; it probably is going to be `sys.prefix` / `sys.base_prefix`. My apoligies.

Comment: use a try/except or run `which icdiff` in a process and use the output to determine where or  if it is installed